# class member unique pointer with custom deleter outside initializer list

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

```
class foo {
    foo();
    unique_ptr<T, (void *)(T*)> ptr;
};

foo::foo() {
    bool x = some operation;
    if (!x) throw;
    ptr = unique_ptr<T, (void *)(T*)>(new T(x), deleter);
}
```

This code does not compile because the unique pointer and its deleter get initialized with null (as I don't initialize it in the initializer list). I can't initialize it in the list because it's dependent on the variable `x` as shown above. How can I solve this deadlock?

Comment: Post real code please. What is `deleter`?

Comment: initialise it through a (possibly static) member function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to add a static function that determines what `x` should be and then return it to the constructor of the `unique_ptr` in the member initialization list

```
foo() : ptr(construct_t(), deleter) {}
static T* construct_t()
{
    bool x = some operation;
    if(!x) throw;
    return new T(x);
}
```

Comment: I suppose you meant to return new T or?

Comment: @mkmostafa I forgot to add that.  Thanks

Comment: @mkmostafa Your edit deviates from how you have your code wroking

Comment: can you explain for me your point? I think it respects the same order of operations?

Comment: @mkmostafa Well first you changed it to return a `T` instead of a `T` pointer and second you never used `x`.  Let me edit this into what I think you meant.

Comment: yea these were typos, I'm sorry but I think you got the point :).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
foo()
: ptr(nullptr, deleter)
{
    if (!some operation) { throw AppropriateException(); }
    ptr.reset(new T(true));
}
```

Comment: finally that code compiled although it doesn't look so good to have a nullptr in the initializer list like this :) but it's equivalent to what I wanted to achieve. But I wonder why you can't initialize both to null that would be more consistent!

Comment: @mkmostafa: An alternative: `foo() : ptr((some op) ? new T(true) : throw Exc(), deleter) {}`

Answer (score 1):

working example of using a generator and custom deleter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct bar {};

struct bar_deleter {
    void operator()(bar* p) const noexcept {

        try {
            if (p) {
                std::cout << "deleting p" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "not deleting p" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        catch(...) {
        }
    }
};

bool some_condition()
{
    static int counter = 0;
    return (counter++ % 2) == 0;
}

struct foo {
    using ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<bar, bar_deleter>;

    foo()
    : ptr(bar_generator())
    {}

    static ptr_type bar_generator() {
        if (some_condition()) {
            std::cout << "creating bar" << std::endl;
            return { new bar, bar_deleter{} };
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "not creating bar" << std::endl;
            return { nullptr, bar_deleter{} };
        }
    }

    ptr_type ptr;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    auto v = std::vector<foo>(10);
    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
creating bar
not creating bar
creating bar
not creating bar
creating bar
not creating bar
creating bar
not creating bar
creating bar
not creating bar
deleting p
deleting p
deleting p
deleting p
deleting p
```